# Change value on page upon click using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I have an upvote link. When user clicks on it, it hides the link (with upvote image) and shows image without link. It is very basic, see [jsfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/6d5Lgeum/).

My question is, how can I increase the value in `<span class="vote_no">0</span>` with `+ 1` upon click? So if value in that span tag is `23`, then it should become `24`.

jQuery:

```
jQuery(".vote_link").click(function() {
    // Hide link
    jQuery(this).andSelf().hide();

    // Show image
    jQuery(this).next(".vote_img_sub").show();
});
```

HTML:

```
<div class="vote_cont">
    <span class="vote_no">0</span>
    <a href="#" class="vote_link"><img class="vote_img" src="http://i.myegy.to/images/77e948107f9d.original.gif" width="52" height="30" /></a>
    <img class="vote_img_sub" src="http://i.myegy.to/images/77e948107f9d.original.gif" width="52" height="30" />
</div>
```

Comment: Are you saying that you also want to remove the link after the user clicks the image?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use:

```
 $(this).prev().text(parseInt($(this).prev().text(),10)+1);
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/5ukksen8/)**

Comment: Don't forget the radix when using parseInt.

Comment: @j08691 What do you mean with radix?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt

Answer (score 1):

I would use `.closest()` to find the parent and then use `.find()` to locate `.vote_no` incase your html ever changed:

```
$(this).closest(".vote_cont").find(".vote_no").text(parseInt($(this).prev().text(),10)+1);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6d5Lgeum/1/

Answer (score 0):

Try this too:

`$('.vote_no').text(parseInt($('.vote_no').text())+1)`

Comment: BTW you forgot to add a class selector `.` in front